# Reading Database structure in visual c++

Tags: database, visual-c++, ms-access, mfc

I am trying to write code that will help me read .accdb database structure, meaning it will give me number of tables that are there, their structure i.e. number and name of fields, index info for each table. In short, everything that's related to structure. I am not saying values or data stored in table.

For example, if i have a DB, say xyz.accdb which has 3 tables - table1, table2, table3

table1 has fileds name, no
table2 -> adress, name
table3 -> name, occupation

Now my code should return number of tables i.e. 3, number of fields in each table, which is 2 here in each case, plus name of individual fields in each table.

Any suggestion, idea, piece of code, anything - preferably in MSVC++ - will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: How you're reading the database? OLEDB? ODBC? ADO?

Comment: As @Adriano says, what is the connection? It ptobably can be used to get schema information.

Comment: @Adriano - anyone.. anything... doesnt matter as long as it meets my purpose and solve my problem.

Comment: @Remou - actually only Dao class supports the functionality of reading table schema without query or netn... but difficulty is it can only be used to read .mdb files while i want to read .accdb files. i hope you got ma point.

Comment: You can get the schema of an ACCDB with DAO, but you may need to download ( http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 ) Otherwise, you can use a connection object.

Comment: @Remou - but how?? i mean i tried a few things in past cpl of days.. but without any success. i downloaded that file but same results. CDaoDatabase class of mfc it still supports only .mdb files while ACEDAO deosnt allow me to read structure directly.

Comment: I do not know C++, but very little research shows me that CDaoDatabase is deprecated ( http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?t=510425 ) and that you can use ADODB with C++ ( http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/intro_to_ado_in_c++.html ). From there, all you need is the right connection string ( http://connectionstrings.com ), keeping in mind that the datatype returned by ADO schemas may not be the best match. Lists of tables, fields, queries etc can easily be obtained in other languages from the ADO connection, so I imagine a little research will show how to do this in C++.

Comment: The first link in my comment above also mentions ATL OLEDB Consumer classes, I imagine that this will also give you a connection object and from there it should be a short step to a schema. You should now have enough key words to rough something out and sample code will get you a better path to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the desired information from the `MSysObjects` table:

Sample query for tables:

```
SELECT MSysObjects.Name
FROM MsysObjects
WHERE (Left$([Name],1)<>"~")
AND (Left$([Name],4) <> "Msys")
AND (MSysObjects.Type)=1
ORDER BY MSysObjects.Name;
```

See [How can I retrieve names of database objects (queries /forms/ table/ reports/ modules/ macros) using a query?](http://access.mvps.org/access/queries/qry0002.htm) for more examples.

Comment: It is quite common for these tables to be inaccessible from outside of MS Access due to permission issues that can be very difficult to get around. I would not recommend the unsupported system tables for working outside of MS Access.

Comment: I admit this offers merely a starting point. A more reliable way of solving this problem would surely be to use Office Automation for Access. I was tempted to turn this question down because it doesn't show the least effort while simple searching already turns up a lot of helpful starting points.

Comment: @Filburt sorry to disappoint you.. but i searched, surfed.. alot.. still doing so.. but everything i found needed some query or other to enter the database, its already open.. and my prob is if there is an unknown DB and i want to know table name in it,,, how would i do that>

Comment: @Filburt - p.s. posting here is last option. THanks anyway.